# Can't upload Instant App to Google Play

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I've successfully built release instant app version of the Android app on Android Studio 3.0 Canary 3. After the submission to Google Play I get strange error.[google play error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFf83.png). Could you help me fix this error?

Comment: Can you upload an apk from a canary android studio version? not sure about that.

Comment: Firstly, the android studio does not fill up the apk , secondly, she does not even collect them, Collects the Gredl

Comment: Unfortunately that error doesn't help debug very much. Are you able to share the Instant App zip file? If you can't share, then try and create a sample that can reproduce and share that Instant App zip file.

Comment: Maybe that's due to 4MB size limit? Does your base module + any feature module take less than 4MB?

Comment: Of course I have less than 4 MB

Comment: @KitKat Do you have any updates? I'm getting the same error.

Comment: @mol 
I downloaded a simple application in Google Play, all ok, I did not get such an error. What is the problem I do not know.

Comment: At the moment, this message is not well defined, but the Developer Console is extra sensitive with Instant App manifests. Do you have anything in your manifests that references a resource? (some fields may not be allowed, so try hardcoding the strings)

Comment: If you still have issues with uploading, you can submit your APK to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=316045&template=1018787 for inspection.

Comment: Since then, the upload error messages have been much better defined, but if you still get generic ambiguous errors, it is best if you submit your Instant App APK ZIP file to Google's IssueTracker.